# How to determine ground and power wires in USB 2.0 with not standard colors?

Tags: usb, cables, wire

My USB 2.0 cable has 4 wires: blue, white, yellow and transparent. I want to connect it to a LED strip that has 2 wires: red (+5V) and white (GND). How can I find ground and power wires among those 4 wires in USB?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Try connecting the USB cable to a power source and with a multimeter check which two pins have +5V between them.

Answer (score 2):

Simply use a multimeter in resistance or continuity mode and find the wires that connect to pin 1 (VCC) and pin 4 (GND) of the USB connector.